# linear programing: find max number of shares of stock to purchase given a budget

Tags: python, linear-programming

The problem I am working on is this: say i have 10k, and I want to buy 3 stocks: AMZN, CBOE, CDW. and my goal is the calculate the max number of shares I can purchase and stay within 10k.

`X*amzn_price+Y*cboe_price+Z*cdw_price <= 10000`

I did the below code based on this [example](https://realpython.com/linear-programming-python/#example-2):

```
from scipy.optimize import linprog
import yfinance as yf


def linearProblem(dict):
    obj = list(dict.values())
    lhs_ineq = [obj]

    rhs_ineq = [10000]

    opt = linprog(c=obj, A_ub=lhs_ineq, b_ub=rhs_ineq, method = "revised simplex")



# Press the green button in the gutter to run the script.
def getPrice():
    symbol_list = ['AMZN', 'CBOE', 'CDW']
    symbol_list_dict = {}

    for symbol in symbol_list:
        ticker = yf.Ticker(symbol).info
        market_price = ticker['regularMarketPrice']
        symbol_list_dict[symbol] = market_price

    return symbol_list_dict


if __name__ == '__main__':
    symbol_price_dict = getPrice()

    linearProblem(symbol_price_dict)
```

but the result is confusing with a fun of 0? I don't think I am inputting my equation right.

```
{'AMZN': 88.45, 'CBOE': 124.14, 'CDW': 184.2}
[88.45, 124.14, 184.2]
3
1
     con: array([], dtype=float64)
     fun: 0.0
 message: 'Optimization terminated successfully.'
     nit: 0
   slack: array([10000.])
  status: 0
 success: True
       x: array([0., 0., 0.])
```

Comment: `calculate the max number of shares I can purchase and stay within 10k`: Just buy the cheapest one? Are you sure this is the exact criteria?

Comment: `linprog` minimizes the objective function, and the objective function you've provided is the total cost of the purchased shares, so linprog just says... don't buy any.

Comment: @Selcuk good point, so I should add additional constraints such as the share count for each stock must be as least 1, basically the goal is to have a diverse portfolio of stocks and spread the 10k amongst the different companies.

Comment: @D.Zou That still doesn't require any fancy optimisation algorithm: Buy 1 each of the expensive ones, then fill the rest of your budget with the cheapest.

Comment: thx this is helping me fleshing out my criterias, ok so i shoud add no stock should exceed a certain percentage of my portfolio. I am picking 3 here as an example, eventually I have a list of 50 or so stocks.

Comment: That's still just going to buy as many of the cheapest shares as possible. I hope you're not planning to actually use this program to make your investment decisions, because you're clearly woefully underprepared, and you haven't thought through the consequences of the optimization objectives and constraints you're setting. You'd be far better off just buying and holding low-fee index funds than trying to apply linear programming.

Comment: yeah no this is just an idea i am experimenting with

Answer (score 1):

I have used Google-ortool's CP-SAT solver. Please have a look at the below solution. You may add more constraints based on your requirements.

```
import string
import random
from ortools.sat.python import cp_model as cp

stocks = list(string.ascii_lowercase)

stock_price = {}
for stk in stocks:
    stock_price[stk] = random.randint(1, 100)

# decision variables
dv_pick_stocks = {}
for stk in stocks:
    dv_pick_stocks[stk] = model.NewBoolVar("")
    
# constraint
model.Add(sum(dv_pick_stocks[stk] * stock_price[stk] for stk in stocks) <= 500)

# decision variable to hold number of stocks selected
dv_num_stock_selected = model.NewIntVar(0, len(stocks), "")

model.Add(dv_num_stock_selected == sum(dv_pick_stocks[stk] for stk in stocks))

model.Maximize(dv_num_stock_selected)

solver = cp.CpSolver()
solver.Solve(model)

# inspect the solution
solver.Value(dv_num_stock_selected)

[(stk, stock_price[stk]) for stk in stocks if solver.Value(dv_pick_stocks[stk]) > 0]
```